# FaterCSV Encoding Issue

Tags: ruby-1.8.7, fastercsv

I am using fastercsv gem for csv export with utf-8 encoding.

When ever i export any arabic content in my csv using utf-8 , when i try to open in windows it comes out as some strange characters. where as in ubuntu it comes fine.

I am working with ruby 1.8.7.
fastercsv (1.5.5)
rails 2.3.5

csv_string=FasterCSV.generate(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |csv|
      csv << header_col

csv << data_col
  end

filename = "Print- #{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.xls"

send_data(csv_string, :type => 'text/xls; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => filename)

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me

csv_string=FasterCSV.generate(:col_sep => "\t") do |csv|

end

send_data Iconv.conv("utf-16", "utf-8", csv_string),:type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"